# AngularFire Storage - Dynamically switch between multiple buckets with Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, angularfire2

I am currently using AngularFire to upload my images to firebase storage and then resize using the firebase image resize extension.  This is working well for my profile images at 200x200.

I now want to upload and resize some other images at a different size of 500x500.

I have made another bucket and installed/configured another instance of the firebase extension to resize at 500x500 for anything uploaded to the new bucket.

I can't figure out how to switch between buckets in my app so I can upload profile images to one and the other images to the other bucket.

Has anyone been able to do this with AngularFire?

NOTE:
-I know you can do this with the firebase JS SDK (raw firebase) but I would like to do it with AngularFire if possible to avoid changing my code.

-I also know you can specify multiple resize resolutions with one resize extension instance but this would create a load of unnecessary images as it would create both 200x200 and 500x500 for each upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell it is not possible to do this fully with AngularFire.
I ended up refactoring my code to use raw Firebase for this particular part.  It is pretty similar but the calls and objects are different to what I was using with AngularFire.

```html
constructor(private afStorage: AngularFireStorage) {
   this.defaultBucket = this.afStorage.storage.app.storage();
   this.otherBucket = this.afStorage.storage.app.storage(OTHER_BUCKETNAME);
}

const storageRef = this.otherBucket.ref().child(FILENAME);
   storageRef.put(file).then((snapshot) => {
   console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!', snapshot);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply provide different buckets to different components or modules. The only caveat is you'd have to break out your components by bucket. Or else you could use the raw Firebase sdk.

```html
@Component({
  selector: 'grapez-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  providers: [{ provide: BUCKET, useValue: 'ai-json-annotations-bucket' }],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private storage: AngularFireStorage) {
    // todo: get ai annotation result json files from one bucket and pass them to child component
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'grapez-gif-segments-child-viewer',
  templateUrl: './gif-segments-child-viewer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./gif-segments-child-viewer.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    { provide: BUCKET, useValue: 'ai-gif-segments-bucket' }, // this will override the previously defined BUCKET definition for this component and any of its children
  ],
})
export class GifSegmentsViewerComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() annotations$: Observable<ListResult>;

  constructor(private storage: AngularFireStorage) {
    // todo: take ai annotation result json files and lookup corresponding gif segment files in another bucket
  }
}
```